# Is there any differences between ssh localhost 'command' and command

Tags: shell, ssh

I am working to deploy my application in remote server and want to test it in my local machine.I find I can't run some command use `ssh localhost 'command'` but I can run it directly without ssh.I wonder why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Noninteractive SSH sessions won't run your `.bashrc` etc. It's all in [the manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1): *"If **command** is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."*

Comment: If I want to use `ssh localhost 'command'` to run some command, what should I do?

Comment: Depends on the failure mode. You haven't posted any diagnostics. If you get `command not found`, try using a full `/path/to/command`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is:

```
$ ssh localhost 'command'
```

issues new ssh session to local host and then run the command in new bash

```
$ command
```

is "shortcut" and it runs the new command directly as a subprocess of current shell.

To use the first method, you need to have running `sshd` server on local host, otherwise you will get error.

Comment: While this is correct, I don't think the OP's problem is related to this.